# Need help to understand Probabilty function and expected value

Tags: probability

Can anyone please help me to understand how to do the following question,

given that a random variable $N$ has a range set $R_{N}=\{1,2,3...\}$

and $$P[N \ge n]=\frac{1}{n+1}$$ , $n=1,2,3,...$

How could I find the probability function of $N$ and $E(N)$

I don't know how to approach it. Any please?

Comment: $P(N<n)=1-P(N\ge n)$

Comment: There is in some cases (including this one) a [shortcut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Discrete_distribution_taking_only_non-negative_integer_values) for finding the expectation by just using the cdf. By the way, the expectation here does not exist, or if you prefer it is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(N=n)=P(N \ge n)-P(N \ge n+1)=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)+1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

And

$$E(N)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Comment: Thanks, so would that be it for the function? and then expected to go to infinity?

Comment: @PersonaA Yes that will be the probability function. You can accordingly calculate the expectation.